# softmax is not working: i have syntax error somewhere

Tags: python, deep-learning, max

I'm trying to reach this command:

```
sm(x=[3,4,1])=[0.259,0.705,0.036]
```

However I'm getting an error. Apparently I have a wrong syntax:

[image]

**A NON-PICTURE RESULTS** A minimal reproducible example is this:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm([1,2,-4])

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[39], line 2
      1 import statsmodels.api as sm
----> 2 sm([1,2,-4])

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: The command you're trying to reach and the line in the image do not match.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read the help section before asking questions. In particular, don't post screenshots when you could have copied the code and also please include all relevant code to form a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal OK. How can I fix it ?

Comment: You... edit the line. And replace it with what you wanted in the first place.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal If I knew how to edit it to get a correct result I wouldn't ask.

Comment: read the docs https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/gettingstarted.html

Comment: The first line seems correct as per the [Docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api-structure.html#api-import-for-interactive-use). In JuPyter, it's wise to separate the imports from the rest of the code. The issue you're having is that you've assigned `sm` to the module you've imported, which you can't call as function. Type "sm." and then use tab to show the available options, it's likely you need to call a method from `sm`

Comment: @Harrison After `tab` at `.sm` I cannot obtain any `softmax` function computing this characteristic.

Comment: How do you know that there should be a softmax function? There is none in the documentation at https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

You can use the scipy package to calculate softmax as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax

x=[3,4,1]
m = softmax(x)
print(m)

# [0.25949646 0.70538451 0.03511903]
```

Comment: Great. But why so many downvotes before you have given a nice answer ?

Comment: I did not downvote but I imagine it's because you posted some code as an image. If anyone were trying to help they would have to retype your code. Don't think of it as rating the importance of your question but rather encouraging the original poster to abide by certain expected standards.

Comment: Could you kindly help me how to get rid off this error and use `tab` at `sm.` ? `AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[93], line 3
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import statsmodels.api as sm
----> 3 sm.softmax([1,2])

AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.api' has no attribute 'softmax'` **I'm unable to get the right shape of this** `Type "sm." and then use tab to show the available options, it's likely you need to call a method from sm` as suggested by Harrison.

Comment: @user1766349 Have you realized that statsmodels does not have a softmax function, so what you are trying to do will never work? Not sure why you think there is a softmax in sm.